# Div SlideInLeft, Stop for a 3 Sec, then SlideOutRight

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I'm learning css transition animation from [Dan Eden’s wonderful animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)
I need to create a div that slideinleft, stop at the center of the page for a few seconds, then  SlideOutRight.

Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LhYTd/1/). I tried to remove the class and replace it with the new one.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("div.slideLeft").removeClass("slideLeft").addClass("slideOutRight");
}, 1000);
```

thank you

Comment: Is it your jQuery correctly loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important thing missing in your example is `animation-fill-mode` CSS property. It specifies how a CSS animation should apply styles to its target before and after it is executing.

Read more about `animation-fill-mode` [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode).

Check out the [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pajusmar/fjZ9E/2/).